# How to deal with a ToolStripMenuItem in this case?

Tags: .net, winforms, toolstrip

This is a CLR Project (.NET Framework 4.5).

I have a `ContextMenuStrip` which is displayed when the right mouse button is pressed on a `ToolStripMenuItem`, since `ToolStripMenuItem` has no `ContextMenuStrip` property I had to set the right click event in the `MouseUp` event like this:

```
private: System::Void itemToolStripMenuItem_MouseUp(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ e) {
    if (e->Button == System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Right) {
        this->contextMenuStrip1->Show(this->menuStrip1, 
        this->menuStrip1->PointToClient(System::Drawing::Point(this->Cursor->Position.X, this->Cursor->Position.Y)));
    }
}
```

I want the `DropDown` to remain open after a right mouse button click, I know that there's an `AutoClose` property that I could set to false:

```
private: System::Void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(System::Object^ sender, System::ComponentModel::CancelEventArgs^ e) {
    this->itemsToolStripMenuItem->DropDown->AutoClose = false;
}
```

The problem is when setting `AutoClose` to false it won't close the `DropDown` anymore. I couldn't find a `Leave` event to close the `DropDown` and set `AutoClose` back to true.

I also need to keep a `DropDown` item highlighted after a right mouse button click.
This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `menu.DropDown.Closing += ...;` event is used to prevent the menu from closing if an item was right clicked. The `IsSelected` property is overridden in a derived `ToolStripMenuItem3` class in order to appear to remain selected.

```
public class MyForm : Form {

    MenuStrip menubar = new MenuStrip { Dock = DockStyle.Top };
    ToolStripMenuItem menu = new ToolStripMenuItem("Menu");
    ToolStripDropDown menuRemove = new ToolStripDropDown();
    ToolStripMenuItem miRemove = new ToolStripMenuItem("Remove");
    ToolStripItem miClickedItem = null;
    Object tag = new Object();

    public MyForm() : base() {
        var item1 = new ToolStripMenuItem3("Item1");
        var item2 = new ToolStripMenuItem3("Item2");
        var item3 = new ToolStripMenuItem3("Item3");
        menu.DropDownItems.AddRange(new [] { item1, item2, item3 });
        menubar.Items.Add(menu);
        this.MainMenuStrip = menubar;

        Controls.Add(menubar);

        menuRemove.Items.Add(miRemove);

        menu.DropDown.MouseClick += DropDown_MouseClick;
        menu.DropDown.Closing += DropDown_Closing;

        menuRemove.Closed += menuRemove_Closed;
        menuRemove.ItemClicked += menuRemove_ItemClicked;
    }

    private class ToolStripMenuItem3 : ToolStripMenuItem {

        public ToolStripMenuItem3(String text) : base(text) { }

        public override bool Selected {
            get {
                bool b = base.Selected;
                return b || this.Tag != null;
            }
        }
    }

    void menuRemove_Closed(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosedEventArgs e) {
        if (miClickedItem != null) {
            miClickedItem.Tag = null;
            miClickedItem.Invalidate();
            miClickedItem = null;
            menu.DropDown.Refresh();
        }

        // There is a bug that prevents the DropDown from auto-closing.
        // The menu.DropDown.Closing event is no longer received.
        // Calling Visible = true fixes this problem.
        menu.DropDown.Visible = true;
        bool inside = menu.DropDown.Bounds.Contains(Cursor.Position);
        if (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked) { } // Remove clicked, keep menu open
        else if (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.AppClicked) {
            if (!inside)
                menu.DropDown.Close(); // mouse was clicked outside of the menu bounds
        }
        else
            menu.DropDown.Close();
    }

    void menuRemove_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.ClickedItem == miRemove) {
            menu.DropDown.Items.Remove(miClickedItem);
            miClickedItem = null;
            if (menu.DropDown.Items.Count == 0)
                menu.DropDown.Close(ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.CloseCalled);
        }
    }

    void DropDown_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e) {
        e.Cancel = (miClickedItem != null);
    }

    void DropDown_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        var dropDown = (ToolStripDropDown) sender;
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
            Point p = e.Location;
            if (miClickedItem != null) {
                miClickedItem.Tag = null;
                miClickedItem.Invalidate();
            }

            miClickedItem = dropDown.GetItemAt(p);
            if (miClickedItem != null) {
                // miClickedItem is null if the mouse click is on the border of the menu
                miClickedItem.Tag = tag; // any non-null object
                menuRemove.Show(dropDown, p);
                miRemove.Select();
                dropDown.Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        if (disposing) {
            if (menuRemove != null) {
                menuRemove.Dispose();
                menuRemove = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ToolStripMenuItem with built-in close button]

The `ToolStripMenuItemX` class:

```
public class MyForm2 : Form {

    MenuStrip menubar = new MenuStrip { Dock = DockStyle.Top };
    ToolStripMenuItem menu = new ToolStripMenuItem("Menu");

    public MyForm2() : base() {
        var item1 = new ToolStripMenuItemX("Item1");
        var item2 = new ToolStripMenuItemX("Item2");
        var item3 = new ToolStripMenuItemX("Item3");
        menu.DropDownItems.AddRange(new [] { item1, item2, item3 });
        menubar.Items.Add(menu);
        this.MainMenuStrip = menubar;

        Controls.Add(menubar);
    }
}

public class ToolStripMenuItemX : ToolStripMenuItem {

    DrawItemState closeState = DrawItemState.None;
    bool isHit = false;
    bool cancelClose = false;
    Point ptMouse = Point.Empty;
    ToolStripDropDown menuCurrent;
    bool dispose = false;

    public ToolStripMenuItemX(String text) : base(text) {
    }

    protected override void OnParentChanged(ToolStrip oldParent, ToolStrip newParent) {
        base.OnParentChanged(oldParent, newParent);
        if (newParent is ToolStripDropDown) {
            var menu = (ToolStripDropDown) newParent;
            menu.Closing += menu_Closing;
            menuCurrent = menu;
        }
    }

    void menu_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e) {
        if (cancelClose || isHit)
            e.Cancel = true;

        if (dispose) {
            // after the MouseUp event, this menu_Closing is called immediately after, one last time
            // unhook the event and dispose this item
            menuCurrent.Closing -= menu_Closing;
            menuCurrent = null;
            Dispose();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs mea) {
        ptMouse = mea.Location;
        var r = GetCloseRectangle();
        closeState = (ptMouse.X >= r.X ? DrawItemState.HotLight : DrawItemState.Selected);
        if (!isHit && mea.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
            // originally the user clicked the item, but then moved the mouse over the X button
            // in this case, don't close the 
            cancelClose = (ptMouse.X >= r.X);
        }
        base.OnMouseMove(mea);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        closeState = DrawItemState.None;
        cancelClose = false;
        isHit = false;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) { 
        var r = GetCloseRectangle();
        isHit = r.Contains(e.Location);
        cancelClose = isHit;
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e) {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        cancelClose = false;

        // OnMouseUp is called after the 'Closing' event is processed, so setting canceClose has no effect here
        var r = GetCloseRectangle();
        if (isHit) {
            if (r.Contains(e.Location)) {
                // remove the menu item, keep the drop down menu open
                menuCurrent.Items.Remove(this);
                menuCurrent.Invalidate();
                dispose = true; // flags this item for disposal
            }
        }
    }

    public override bool Selected {
        get {
            Rectangle r = GetCloseRectangle();
            return (ptMouse.X >= r.X ? false : base.Selected);
        }
    }

    private Rectangle GetCloseRectangle() {
        var r = this.ContentRectangle;
        int h = r.Height;
        return new Rectangle(r.Right - h, r.Y, h, h);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        var g = e.Graphics;
        if (closeState == DrawItemState.HotLight || closeState == DrawItemState.Selected) { 
            var r = GetCloseRectangle();

            if (closeState == DrawItemState.HotLight) {
                var renderer = (ToolStripProfessionalRenderer) this.DropDown.Renderer;
                var ct = renderer.ColorTable;
                Color c1 = (isHit ? ct.ButtonPressedHighlight : ct.ButtonSelectedHighlight);
                Color c2 = (isHit ? ct.ButtonPressedBorder : ct.ButtonSelectedBorder);

                using (var b = new SolidBrush(c1))
                    g.FillRectangle(b, r);

                using (var p = new Pen(c2))
                    g.DrawRectangle(p, r);
            }

            using (var sf = StringFormat.GenericDefault) {
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                g.DrawString("x", this.Font, SystemBrushes.ActiveCaptionText, r, sf);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, this solution seems to work but there are a few tweaks to be done, my custom controls are in a `.dll` library so I need to get rid of `MyForm` type, what could be used instead of a `MyForm` instance in order to store the `miClickedItem`? Also `menuRemove_Closed` closes the `DropDown` when right clicking on another `ToolStripMenuItem`, I mean it should let the user right click on another items without closing the `DropDown`. Can you update your answer with these tweaks? So I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Simple The solution is updated. The Remove item is now functional, and the menu stays open if an item is removed. If the Remove menu is displayed, and the user clicks off somewhere else, then both menus are closed. `MyForm` was replaced with a `non-null` object, set as the `Tag` property in order to remain in the `Selected` state.

Comment: Good! It works! But once again there're a few issues I noticed: #1 A consecutive right mouse button click on another item will cause the `DropDown` to close. #2 After a removal the `DropDown` should still open in case the user wants to remove another item, so the user doesn't have to reopen it again. I commented out a line to prevent it to close but that's where a issue comes up, after clicking on Remove the item gets removed and the `DropDown` still open, but the `DropDown` gets stuck and the only way to close it is by clicking on the `DropDown` again which is not convenient for the user.

Comment: After right clicking on one item, and then right clicking on another item, the menu stays open for me. After removing an item, the menu stays open for me. Good luck, I'm done.

Comment: Actually there's no need to comment any line, I did put a `ToolStripMenuItem` in the wrong place, forgive me, and forget about the comment out part, it works as intended, however the only way to close the `DropDown` after a removal is clicking on it again, plus the consecutive right clicking on another item closes the `DropDown`, maybe CLR and C# are different in this case, maybe a `Control` works different. I will find it out. Thank you.

Comment: There's no problem in the CLR, actually in your code or maybe in the `.NET Framework 4.5`, because I just copied and pasted your answer in a C# `Windows Forms` App (.NET Framework 4.5) it's indeed not working as expected. What version of .NET Framework you used? Not sure if you understood me when I say the consecutive right clicks, I mean right click on Item3 then right click on Item2 or Item1 so that will close the entire popup menu, also after removing, the user is not able to close the the popup menu by clicking outside it. When I say popup menu is the one that holds all ToolStripMenuItems.

Comment: @Simple I am using `.NET 4.5.2`. I tested again and see where was an oversight. Now, the `menuRemove_Closed` method is updated so that it does not close the main menu if the mouse was clicked inside the main menu's rectangle bounds.

Comment: Nice! I'm accepting this answer, thank you! By the way there's still an issue in the `menuRemove_ItemClicked` when an Item gets removed the main menu gets stuck, I mean it will not be able to close the main menu by clicking outside of it, I fixed it though by showing the main menu again: `if (menu.DropDown.Items.Count == 0) menu.DropDown.Close(ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.CloseCalled);
else menu.DropDown.Show();` in the `menuRemove_ItemClicked`, check it out, you might want to update your answer in case someone else try it and find out this issue.

Comment: Setting `menu.DropDown.Visible = true;` in the `menuRemove_Closed` method seems to fix that problem. Seems like a bug in `.NET`.

Comment: Yeah setting `Visible` to true works! By the way it may sound crazy and you may have no patience for this anymore but this is interesting that I found a critical bug still (lol), not sure if you can reproduce this but if you carefully right click in the very very bottom of the main menu border you get the following exception: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApp1.exe
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` I bet it has something to do with `menu.DropDown.Bounds.Contains(Cursor.Position)` because it's in the very border.

Comment: @Simple I reproduced the exception, and updated the answer. Have you considered a custom `ToolStripMenuItemX` that has a built-in remove button? (see image added to answer).

Comment: Perfect! Now I guess there's ZERO issues. The X button seems a good idea, it would be faster to the user to remove an item, it would save time and clicks, can you update your answer with that? But keep the `menuRemove` function because I'm planning to implement an Edit function later, and in case the user does not spot the X button it's good to keep both ways to remove an item.

Comment: @Simple The answer is updated to include the `ToolStripMenuItemX ` class. Integrating both solutions is more than I have time for at the moment.

Comment: Another idea: If the popup menu only contains two items, Edit and Delete, then draw an Edit  button before the X button. Either a `pencil` character (using the `Segoe UI Symbol` font), or `...` could be used for the edit button `Text`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this alternative answer, I wish I could upvote +2, great job.